# Rails, where does CarrierWave store files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, carrierwave

Couldn't find/understand good documentation on this. I wonder where uploads that are done by CarrierWave goes? As from my understanding it goes directly into the db, right? Could I force it to store (or create like a reference to the file) in my assets pipeline? Today had an issue when couldn't use `image_tag` since it grabs asset only from the assets pipeline. Could it be that letting users to store files in asset pipeline could be a potentially very risky and harmful?

So my questions:

- Can I store / reference file in the assets pipeline?
- Would it be a good idea?

Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your uploader you'll see a method called `store_dir` the default looks like this...

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

So for an attachment named "oranges.jpg" in a field called `image` in a model called `FilmReview` in the record with id `45` it's stored in...

```
public/uploads/film_review/image/45/oranges.jpg
```

You can change `store_dir` to store the image in a different directory, or upload it to a cloud service like AWS... see railscasts or other resources for examples of how to do ths.

Comment: Oh, very nice. Now it made it more clear to me. Many thanks!